# C++ program compiled with Clang crashes when new operator is overloaded and outputs to std::cout

Tags: c++, clang, new-operator, cout, clang++

I am using Clang version 10.0.0 on Windows 10.

This program

```
#include <iostream>
// without this operator the program works just fine
void* operator new(std::size_t nrOfBytes) {
    std::cout << "allocate " << nrOfBytes << " bytes on heap" << std::endl;
    void* p = malloc(nrOfBytes);
    if (p) {
        return p;
    } else {
        throw std::bad_alloc{};
    }
}
int main() {
    printf("START\n");
    return 0;
}
```

crashes with return code -1073741819 after having been compiled with

> clang++ Main.cpp -std=c++17

Of course, the very same invocation of Clang produces an error-free program when there is no overloaded new operator.

Any hints ?

Comment: Probably not the issue but you might also want to overload void* operator new[] in this case and delete/[].
EDIT: Since C++17 operator new also takes std::align_val_t al as second argument.

Comment: @Chris: Tried this but didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to delete cout operations from "new".
May be some stream operations need other "new"?

Comment: True. printf() should avoid that.

Comment: Replacing the cout operations actually made the program run. Clang seems to produce a recursion with cout in the overloaded new operator. Notice also that both gcc and MSVS did produce an error-free program with the original version.

Comment: @Angle.Bracket: Very, *very* much implementation-specific. My own `printf()` implementation, for example, doesn't do dynamic allocations in the first place...